# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{x^2y}{y+x^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find $$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\dfrac{x^2y}{y+x^2}}.$$

I tried with iterated limits, $y=mx,\;\;y=kx^2$ but everyone throws me that the limit is $0$.

I have been told that I have to see the contour lines, but I did not understand completely how to do it. For example

$C_0=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid \dfrac{x^2y}{x+y^2}=0\right\}=\{y=0\;\wedge\;(x,y)\neq (0,0)\}$, or

$C_1=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid \dfrac{x^2y}{x+y^2}=1\right\}=\left\lbrace y=\dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1}\;\wedge\;x\neq 1\;\wedge\;x\neq -1\right\rbrace$.

I think that in $ C_1 $ the point goes through the curve, and the curve exists. What does that tell me?

So how do I prove (or not) the existence of the limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Try something like $y=x^4-x^2$

Comment: @kingW3 I am noob with multivariable calculus, so may I ask you how did you notice that change?

Comment: Well if $y=kx^t$ you get $0$, if $y>0$ then the following inequality by qbert holds, so $y$ must be negative and it's convenient that you have $-x^2$ term and you guess that $x^4-x^2$ works. Also another way to look at it that disaster happens near $y=-x^2$ so you can exploit that.

Comment: Very simple! That's fine for me.

Comment: @kingW3 Could you explain me what is "near $y=-x^2$" please?

Comment: In a neighbourhood of $-x^2$ i.e for $y=-x^2+\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$

Comment: @manooooh Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi The problem is that kingW3 solved the question without having published an answer. And voting a solution that does not correspond to him seems unfair. What should I do?

Comment: @manooooh You are absolutely not forced to select a solution of course, I've just recall that because many people here ask for help and when the OP is solved they simply forget to accept an answer. In this case you could ask to kingW3 to add his answer in the correct section or also let the OP unaccepted. Thanks, Bye.

Comment: What happened is that he answered first, if he had already accepted any of the answers they gave me. I do not have any kind of preference, only that it seemed unfair to me to give an answer to the person who answered me after having solved the question. @kingW3 , would you like to provide an answer?

Comment: @manooooh I should have posted an answer before (but I was lazy :P) anyway I've added an answer so feel free to accept it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y>0$ then $$\bigg|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y} \bigg|\leq \bigg|\frac{x^2y}{y} \bigg|=x^2$$
Now checking $y<0$ one can see that for $y$ in the neighbourhood of $-x^2$ that the denominator goes to $0$ independent of the numerator.

If we write $y=-x^2+\epsilon$ then we get $$\lim_{(x,\epsilon)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2(\epsilon -x^2)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{(x,\epsilon)\to(0,0)}x^2+\frac{-x^4}{\epsilon}=\lim_{(x,\epsilon)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x^4}{\epsilon}$$
So we can see that $\epsilon=kx^4$ gives a different value for the limit so it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist.

In order for such limits to exist the denominator must have even exponents on $x$ and $y$. For example in your case let $$y=x^k-x^2$$ for any very large value of $k$. This will give (minus) infinity as a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

- for $x=y=t\to 0\implies{\dfrac{x^2y}{y+x^2}}=\frac{t^3}{t+t^2}=\frac{t^2}{1+t}\to 0$
- for $x=t \quad y=t^5-t^2 \quad t\to 0^+\implies{\dfrac{x^2y}{y+x^2}}=\frac{t^{7}-t^4}{t^5-t^2+t^2}=\frac{t^{7}-t^4}{t^5}=\frac{t^2-1}{t}\to -\infty$

thus the limit doesn't exist.